# Custom Settings-class exception on first use (ApplicationSettingsBase)

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings, applicationsettingsbase

Reading the Settings for the first time (-before they've been set) throws an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception.

Setting a default value using [DefaultSettingValueAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.defaultsettingvalueattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) cannot be done in the real case because it's not a simple type like in the my example of an int, and can't be described as a string. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.defaultsettingvalueattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> DefaultSettingValueAttribute requires that the default value can be
>   represented as a string.

How should this be avoided?

**More info:**

Of course I can wrap it in a `try-catch` block, but that should be left for exceptional cases, whereas this is a normal thing - every user who will use the application for the first time will encounter this. And `try`ing every time because of that first time seems wrong.

So what’s the correct solution?

Here's the code:

```
public class MySettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    public int MyInt
    {
        get { return (int)(this["MyInt"]); } // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        set { this["MyInt"] = value; }
    }
}
```

And called so:

```
MySettings s = new MySettings();
int i = s.MyInt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a default value for the setting. I think that should prevent it from memory.

If you can't specify a default, put a check in the getter to see if its null, if it is initialize it to your own default value.

```
get { 

      if(this["MyInt"] == null)
          this["MyInt"] = 0;

      return (int)(this["MyInt"]); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. However, The real case is of a complicated type, not an `int` - so it can't have a default value (because it can't be described as a string.)

Comment: I'll give it a try. I just checked and saw that the exceptin is _not_ by calling the object itself...